# Getting error while importing workflow into QA environment from DEV

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am getting below error while I am trying to import workflow from DEV environment to QA. I was able to import once successful but someone deleted that and now I am trying it again, then it is giving error:

> 04/04/2012 16:56:46 **** Importing Mapping: m_BTTC_Load_T3_T1 ...
>        : Could not find Transformation definition for:  TEMP_BTTC_TABLE_1
>   ** Failed to Import: m_BTTC_Load_T3_T1

Comment: Did you export the workflow with all its dependencies using the Repository Manager?

Comment: I tried importing it from Repository Manager. 1st time it was successful exported from Dev and imported in QA. But someone deleted whole folder from QA, now I am tring to it again, but getting above error. Dependencies what?? Actually I am new, so if you could help.

Comment: How was the file exported? What tool was used? Does it contain the `TEMP_BTTC_TABLE_1` transformation?

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when your mapping is referring to a reusable components (transformation) which is found to be missing. Not necessarily shortcuts, but they can also be the reason of such behavior.

My suggestion is, Re-export (so that the changed dependencies are refreshed in the export file) the workflow from Repository Manager, and then re-import it.